# Qt : how to automate looped slider movement in the background?

Tags: c++, qt

What's the most straightforward approach to have a slider move in a loop at a given speed when a button is pressed? I'm guessing it involves forking a thread that sends the appropriate signals periodically to the slider. Is there an canonical approach example for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use `QPropertyAnimation` to do the job. just set the start value, the end value and the curve you want the value to change

```
QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(slider,"sliderPosition");
//set the duration (how long the animation should run - will change value faster when shorter)
animation->setDuration(1000);
//set the start value - in this case check if value in range of the slider
animation->setStartValue(slider->minimum());
//same as start value
animation->setEndValue(slider->maximum());
//easingCurve defines if it goes straight or bouncing n stuff
animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutCubic);

// as coyote mentioned, you can loop the animation as well (credit him as well ;))
// -1 defines to run forever
animation->setLoopCount(loopCount)

animation->start();
```

Comment: you can also change the loop count to make it run indefinitely

Answer (score 2):

This would just be a matter of updating the slider's position on a timer. So, create a timer and on each  update, call [QSlider::setValue](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#value-prop).

When the value is at maximum, set it back to the minimum and continue.

```
QSlider* pSlider = new QSlider;

QButton * pButton = new QButton("Go");

QTimer* pTimer = nullptr; // C++ 11 nullptr

// On button click, start a timer
connect(pButton, &QButton::clicked(), [=](){

  // exit if already running
  if(pTimer)
      return;       

   pTimer = new QTimer;
   connect(pTimer, &QTimer::timeout, [=](){

       if(pSlider->value()+1 > pSlider->maximum())
           pSlider->setValue(pSlider->minimum());
      else
           pSlider->setValue(++pSlider->value());       
   });
   pTimer->start(1000); // update every second
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QTimer`. Minimal example:

```
QSlider *sl = new QSlider;
QTimer *ttt = new QTimer;
sl->setValue(0);

connect(ttt,&QTimer::timeout,[=]() {
    sl->setValue(sl->value() + 5);
});
sl->show();
ttt->start(500);
```

I used here `C++11` (`CONFIG += c++11` to `.pro` file) and [new syntax of signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), but of course you can use old syntax if you want.

Answer (score 1):

There's no canonical approach to my knowledge.

The timers are given in the other answers, but you can also use the [animation framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html#details), and adjust the speed by adjusting the duration of the animation.

You can set the loopcount to how many times you want the animation to run, for example 1000000 to make it run a long time.